# Which timers are dependent on system time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timer

I haven't tested this yet. I am hoping someone already knows the answer, so I don't have to write a test application, otherwise I will. :)

Usually when I want to compare time, I just store `DateTime.Now` and compare it at a later time. I believe this gives wrong results when the user changes the user's system time somewhere in between.

It made me wonder whether timers behave the same way. Which .NET timers are dependent on the set system time? Consider starting a timer which needs to elapse in one hour. Will it trigger when I set system time one hour forward?

I never really cared about this possible behavior, but it might be important in some scenarios. Which timers are safe against this scenario, and which ones most definitely aren't?

Comment: If you have the liberty to query an NTP server, you could use a simple [NTP class like this](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#GawBxmf1je8/NTP/NtpClient.cs&q=ntp%20lang:c%23).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would be a bit of overkill for a local solution. :)

Comment: None of the timers depend on the system time. That is, the user changing the clock will not affect `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer`, or `System.Threading.Timer`. Nor will it affect `Stopwatch` or `Environment.TickCount`.  Also, there's no "overhead" to using `Stopwatch`. It's not like the value is continually updated. It's lazily evaluated (i.e. `Ticks` is updated when it's referenced).

Comment: @JimMischel, is this information available in `MSDN` or an "Official" source ?

Comment: @Ofiris: Documentation for [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) says: "The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time." If you look up info on the high-resolution performance counter, you'll see that it doesn't depend on the system time.

Comment: @Ofiris: Timers are similar. `System.Threading.Timer` is based on Windows Timer Queue Timers. See that documentation. `System.Timers.Timer` is just a wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is a wrapper around the Windows `SetTimer` and `KillTimer` functions. Documentation for those indicates that they are not dependent on the system time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just [quote Jim Mischel comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128027/which-timers-are-dependent-on-system-time#comment5753163_5128027), as it's the most relevant answer to my question.

> None of the timers depend on the system time. That is, the user
>   changing the clock will not affect `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`,
>   `System.Timers.Timer`, or `System.Threading.Timer`. Nor will it affect
>   `Stopwatch` or `Environment.TickCount`. Also, there's no "overhead" to
>   using `Stopwatch`. It's not like the value is continually updated. It's
>   lazily evaluated (i.e. `Ticks` is updated when it's referenced).
>
> Documentation for [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) says: "The`Stopwatch` measures elapsed time
>   by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the
>   installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution
>   performance counter, then the `Stopwatch` class uses that counter to
>   measure elapsed time." If you look up info on the high-resolution
>   performance counter, you'll see that it doesn't depend on the system
>   time
>
> Timers are similar. `System.Threading.Timer` is based on Windows Timer
>   Queue Timers. See that documentation. System.Timers.Timer is just a
>   wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is a
>   wrapper around the Windows `SetTimer` and `KillTimer` functions.
>   Documentation for those indicates that they are not dependent on the
>   system time.

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to solve similar problem.  I turn out to use [`System.Diagnostic.StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to replace all [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx).  [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) will use the high frequency clock if present.  So, it's more accurate and independent of the system clock change.  However, if high frequency clock is not present, it will fall back to use system clock again.

According to my testing, all my machines have high frequency clock, including the machines in VM.

About the Timer, as far as I remember, it isn't dependent on the system clock.  However, you don't really want to use Timer to track the time because the Timer callback events may be deferred by some other events.

Comment: I don't really need the events, I would solely use it for the elapsed time, to improve on the `DateTime.Now` approach. It feels weird using `Stopwatch` as I don't need the ultra high precision (and possibly the overhead?). There must be a reason why they placed it in the `Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: @Steven All three Timers class are calling your callback or raising your events after a period of time. `System.Windows.Form.Timer` should be using `WM_TIMER` which is sharing the same message loop with other Windows messages. This is what I meant. For the other Timers class, I just tried `System.Timers.Timer`, it looks like it is not dependent on system clock.

Comment: `Stopwatch` should be lower overhead, because it doesn't have to calculate year/month/day information, it's just an elapsed time.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I believe the higher precision would cause an overhead. Furthermore, wouldn't the year/month/day calculations happen lazily?

Comment: @Harvey Kwok: Thanks a lot. So for a safe time reference `Stopwatch` does seem to be the only suitable solution.

Comment: On many modern (aka cheap) motherboards, Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks is generated from a chipset time source that has a very high resolution but very poor accuracy.  It is not a substitute for a Timer that runs off a clock tick interrupt that's calibrated with an Internet Time Server correction.  Stopwatch is good to compare short intervals only.

Comment: @Steven: There's a separate circuit in the CPU, and also a chip on the motherboard, that are dedicated to high resolution timing.  There's not extra overhead, it's not like the CPU is having to run timer handling code more often.

Comment: @Hans: Stopwatch doesn't have ANY accuracy at all.  It only does elapsed time, not even capable of reporting absolute time.  If Windows is using RDTSC as its precision time source on an CPU with variable clock rate, that's a Windows bug.  I think it's smart enough to use the timer chip instead.  And the clock interrupt is not calibrated with internet time (the elapsed time accounted per interrupt may be, but the interrupt isn't affected in any way).

Comment: @Hans Passant: This could be a separate answer! What do you suggest then? Running a timer with interval of 1ms and using this as a safe time reference? Same goes for @Ben Voigt.

Comment: @Steven: `I haven't tested this yet`.  Test it.

Comment: Another possibility is `Environment.TickCount`, although there are rollover issues that you have to deal with. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On RPi Zero this is what I see:
If you change system clock, Thread.Sleep will stop. If time is set to a value ahead of current time and then you set it back again, Sleep wont work anymore. If you set the time to some time in the past and then again to the current time, it will work as expected.