# Events being raised multiple times

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events

I'm trying to create a class that will create a Relogin after certain time but after the first Relogin it keeps populating. Heres my Code:

```
 Private Shared timer As Timer
Public Shared Event DoSomething As Action(Of Integer)
Private Shared _timesCalled As Integer = 0


Public Shared Sub Start()
    AddHandler DoSomething, AddressOf EventHandler
    timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf timer_Task, Nothing, 0, 1000)
End Sub
Public Shared Sub [Stop]()
    timer.Dispose()
End Sub
Private Shared Sub timer_Task(State As Object)
    _timesCalled += 1

    If _timesCalled = 15 Then  'Should Raise event every 15s
        RaiseEvent DoSomething(_timesCalled)
    End If

End Sub

Private Shared Sub EventHandler(ByVal EventNumber As Integer)
    My.Application.Dispatcher.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf OpenLogin))
End Sub
Private Shared Sub OpenLogin() 'This event fires multiple times after the first Event

    Dim x As New MainWindow
    x.ShowDialog() 'Dialog stops code from continuing.
    x = Nothing
    _timesCalled = 0

End Sub
```

Open_Login() fires multiple times after the first or second time. Doesn't seem to cause the same problem when I replace "MainWindow" object with a messagebox. Please Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out it was my coding. Everytime MainWindow would load it would run Start() creating a new instance of Timer. Correct issue. Thanks for viewing

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the fact that your issue seems to be solved - using an unsynchronised counter is not a reliable way to have an event fired every predetermined period.

The timer event itself fires from a separate .NET managed thread and subsequently, the `_timesCalled` variable can be accessed from multiple threads. So it is possible that while you are re-setting `_timesCalled=0` from your main thread another thread from the default threadpool is about to overwrite this with `_timesCalled=14`.

In your specific example it is simpler and more straightforward to reschedule the timer event after you’ve finished handling one. That way you can also account for the time it took you to process the event and the timer inaccuracies and lag.

```
Public Shared Sub Start()    
    ...
    ' assuming this runs only once
    timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf timer_Task, Nothing, 15000,  Timeout.Infinite)    
End Sub

Private Shared Sub timer_Task(State As Object)    
        RaiseEvent DoSomething(_timesCalled)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OpenLogin()
    Dim x As New MainWindow
    x.ShowDialog()
    x = Nothing

    ' Reschedule the timer again here, adjust the 15000 if necessary, maybe prefer timer.ChangeTime(...) instead    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you for help. I will sure change that. I do have another question for you, How does this timer keep track of its milliseconds. What I'm trying to do is set a predetermine amount of time before the session ends and asks to relogin. I hope the Timer is not dependent on Windows Time.

Comment: The .NET timer is dependent on the Windows time and is bounded by the resolution of the underlying operating system timings. That underlying resolution is around 15-20ms.

Comment: Can that cause a loop hole from never ending the session. I would like my session to last 48hrs before asked to relogin. I just don't want the user to change the time to "extend" the session timeout

Comment: It's hard to say. Maybe it is better for you to formulate that question alongside the design considerations and your current solution as a separate question on SO? You'll get more eyes looking at it and usually get an excellent feedback.

Comment: Thanks for helping me just found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128027/which-timers-are-dependent-on-system-time